# Build a "printMe" method in to an Objective C class?

Tags: objective-c

I have some Entities holding values for my program.
E.g. a "Person" Entity has synthesized properties for the values "name", "age", "address" etc.

I wish to build a "printMe" method on the Entity, so that invoking this method results in the above properties being printed to the console like "\nPropertyName:Value".

I have done this with Core Data Entities before by using something like this:

```
- (void) printMe {

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NewAirline" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

for (NSString *attr in [entity attributesByName]) {
    //[object setValue:@"n/a" forKey:attr];

    NSLog(@"%@:%@", attr, [self valueForKey:attr]);
}
NSLog(@"*************** end ***************\n");
```

}

The Entity I have in this case is not Core Data and I can't use `attributesByName`. But it should still be key-value compliant so I guess there is a way around this.

My Entity has 20+ properties and I would like to avoid doing it manual by listing each property and calling it by name in NSLog.

Thanks in advance for any help given:)

Comment: You may consider providing a '- (NSString) description;' method and avoid putting NSLog stuff at all in your objects.

Comment: Thank you Frank:) That is a really good idea, it is of course for some caveman-debugging and to test the objects deals correctly with the web service data I pour into them. I never need the data inside the objects, it is always NSLog([myObject description]); from the parent owning the array of objects. I really don't like to "litter" in my objects either and this approach is in tune with the way Objective-C does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Objective-C runtime Api. The function [`class_copyPropertyList`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyPropertyList) gives you all declared properties of a given class. You can then get their names etc using more runtime functions like [`property_getAttributes`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/property_getAttributes) or `property_getName`. Using that name you can access the value in a KVC-compliant manner.

Comment: Thank you Max. I am not that familiar with the runtime API, your help gave me enough to figure it out. I am going to mix your answer and Franks comment:)